# How to generate output file for given input file

Tags: c++, io

I tried

```
freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
```

but somehow it's not working.  Example program:

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
  int t,n;
  cin >> t; 
  while (t--) 
  {
    cin >> n; 
    cout << 2 * n; 
  }
}
```

How to read input from file and generate output in file for above program?

Comment: I am new to hackercup. I have searched for whole day. But none of those were working. So i am asking it here.Deadline is near(2 days).I have to ask here to get responses asap.I have solved the problems but don't want to take risk.

Answer (score 1):

Got answer from some gentleman.Sharing it for wider audience.

I need not change the code for that

After compilation i can just run code this way

```
fileName.exe < input.txt >output.txt
```